# I sent Bitcoin to a Bitcoin Cash eWallet by mistake, what can I do?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

By mistake, I sent some Bitcoin to a Bitcoin Cash eWallet. Is there anything that I can do to get it back?

Comment: I ve always wondered if transaction can be reversed

Answer (score 1):

Do you hold private keys of that Bitcoin Cash eWallet? 
If yes, you need to import private key of that Bitcoin Cash address into any Bitcoin wallet and you will be able to get your bitcoins back.